# How should the gutters be installed on a huge gable dormer?

Tags: roof, gutters

I have a situation similar to this photo (except my "dormer" is 24 feet long), focusing on the upper gutter:  I think it makes the most sense to catch rain/debris from a roof valley in the main gable dormer gutter.

[image]

To do this it looks like the end of the gutter needs to be fabricated to have a smaller angle than the (non-dormer) roof angle.

But my seamless gutter guy is saying this isn't commonly done and the lower gutter is usually the one that catches the valley rain/debris.

Do I need a new seamless guy or is he right?

Comment: the photo is just an example.  the general question I have is if it's better for a roof valley (one formed by a gable dormer in my case) to drain into an immediate gutter at the end of the valley, or to drain to a lower gutter.  the photo shows that at least someone out there has made it so the valley drains to an upper gutter.  I'm just curious if that's the best way to do it or not.  the difference between my situation and the attached photo is that my gable dormer is 24' long (the one in the photo looks to be only about 3' long)

Comment: my gut feeling is that it's better to catch rain at the very end of the valley instead of letting the valley water run to the gutter below.  in this example photo, the upper gutter could have been cut shorter (on the right side of it in the photo) and terminated with a vertical cap, allowing the valley water to run down to the lower gutter.  that's the direction my seamless guy is steering me, but I don't know if he's steering me that way because it's the best way or if because it's the easiest way for him.

Comment: I've done some more research and found a guy who converted a gutter that captured valley water to one that let the valley water run free to a gutter below:  http://meticulousremodeling.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/DSC00433.jpg 
You can see how he left a sizable gap between the valley and the gutter for clearance.
He didn't say why he did this, though.  But with the linked photo in my first post and the linked photo in this post, you can see the 2 things I'm choosing between.  I guess I just don't know which one is better.